# How to make a table look nicer

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am currently working on my master thesis and my tables which are used as a type of matrix simply look awful. How can i make them look much better?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
        &\textgreater& =+ & =- & \textless \\
        \hline
        \textgreater & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \hline
        =+ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \hline
        =- & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \hline
        \textless & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The width of the cells are not consistent and the chars are differing in size, basically i want this to look better. My other solution is to make it in Photoshop, but id prefer to do it in LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While beauty is in the eye of the beerholder, here is one option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{c| *{4}{C{2em}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{>} & =\joinrel+ & =\joinrel- & \multicolumn{1}{c}{<} \\
    \hline
    > & \phantom{-}1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    =\joinrel+ & \phantom{-}0 & 1 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
    =\joinrel- & \phantom{-}0 & 0 & 1 & \phantom{-}0 \\
    < & -1 & 0 & 0 & \phantom{-}1
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may have better off right justifying the first and last columns.

Comment: +1 for beerholder (and the technical merits of the answer, of course).

Comment: It's easier to use `\llap` or `\rlap` to align the columns, in my opinion.

Comment: One last thing, how do i make lines in between all the cells, except the math signs on the outside?

Comment: I suggest adding a little more air between the rows.

Comment: For vertical padding, use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<num>}`, as suggested in [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).

Answer (score 6):

Here is somme more air, and no \phantom, with the `siunitx` package. Some colour, and different widths horizontal and vertical rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\mathversion{bold}}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{document}

\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1em}\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}
  \begin{array}{ @{}>{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\mathversion{bold}}c@{\quad}!{\color{Tomato3}\vrule width 1.2pt}*{4}{S[table-format = 1.0]}}
   & {\thead{>}} & {\thead{=\joinrel+}} & {\thead{=\joinrel-}} & {\thead{<}} \\[-1ex]
    \hline
    > & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    =\joinrel+ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    =\joinrel- & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    < & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\[-2ex]
 &
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When i include `siunitx` i get some conflict with `sistyle` apparently: `Package 'sistyle' incompatible`

Comment: @JavaCake: I never used `sistyle`. As  far as I know, it is no more developed and is superseded by `siunitx`.

Answer (score 2):

Usine memoir class you can also do as shown below

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
      \begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l|rrrr}
    \toprule
           &  \textgreater& \textbf{ =+}  & \textbf{=-} & \textbf{\textless} \\
     \midrule
       \textgreater & \textbf {1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{ -1}\\
       =+ &\textbf{ 0} &\textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} \\
       =- &\textbf{ 0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1}&\textbf{ 0} \\
      \textless &\textbf{ -1} & \textbf{0} &\textbf{0} &\textbf{1}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image: beautytbl]

Comment: The `-` symbols -- in the header row and column as well as in the body of the table -- really ought to be rendered as typographic *minus* signs rather than as the much shorter typographic *dash* (aka hyphen) characters. Also, if you're going to use the macros of the `booktabs` package, don't use vertical lines in the table; conversely, if you really must use vertical bars, don't use the macros of the `booktabs` package. Incidentally, why did you encase the contents of every single cell in a `\textbf` "wrapper"?